# Python XLRD use Range

Tags: python, excel, range, xlrd

I want to assign an excel range to a variable:

```
import xlrd

file = r"C:\Users\Lisa\Desktop\Frank\export.XLSX"
book = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
data = [range("A3:D7")]
```

, but I get an error:

```
    data = [range("A3:D7")]
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The `range` you're using here refers to python Built-in [`range() func`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range), not `xlrd.range`.

Comment: When I use xlrd.range I get the following error:
"AttributeError: module 'xlrd' has no attribute 'range'"

Comment: That's right, it doesn't have that function. I was just pointing out that `range` is Python-related, not xlrd.

Comment: Do you know how I can refer to an excel range? I tried sheet.range but it's not available either

Comment: Do you mean you want your variable 'data' to be the list of values in the cell range of a sheet? Can't be that hard to code this yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the following to extract a block from an XLS file as follows:

```py
from itertools import product
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(r"input.xls")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

# Build a cell lookup table
cell_refs = {xlrd.cellname(r, c) : (c, r) for r, c in product(range(sheet.nrows), range(sheet.ncols))}

def get_cell_range(start_col, start_row, end_col, end_row):
    return [sheet.row_slice(row, start_colx=start_col, end_colx=end_col+1) for row in range(start_row, end_row+1)]

def get_cells(excel_range):
    start_range, end_range = excel_range.split(":")
    return get_cell_range(*cell_refs[start_range], *cell_refs[end_range])


# Use numeric cell references
data = get_cell_range(0, 2, 3, 6)   # A3 to D7
print(data)

# Use Excel range format
data = get_cells("A3:D7")
print(data)
```

`xlrd` works using column and row numbers starting from `0` instead of Excel cell names. It can only convert Excel cell references from col row format to `A1` format  using `xlrd.cellname()`, not the other way around. A workaround is to build your own reverse lookup table using that function.

Note: older versions of XLRD supported Excel XLSX files. Now only XLS files are supported. For XLSX files consider using `openpyxl` or `Pandas`.

Answer (score 1):

The same question arose in me. And I solved it this way.

First I created an inverse function to `xlrd.cellname()` and then I proceeded with the function to get the values ​​of the ranges

```
import xlrd
import re

def parse_cell(cell):
    r = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)")
    m = r.match(cell)
    col = m.group(1).upper()
    number_row = int(m.group(2)) - 1

    ABC = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

    number_col = 0
    for char in col:
        number_col += ABC.index(char)

    return (number_row, number_col)


def get_cell_range_values(sheet, start_cell, end_cell):
    start_cell_parsed = parse_cell(start_cell)
    end_cell_parsed = parse_cell(end_cell)

    data = sheet.col_values(start_rowx=start_cell_parsed[0], colx=start_cell_parsed[1], end_rowx=end_cell_parsed[0] + 1)
    return data


file = r"C:\Users\Lisa\Desktop\Frank\export.XLSX"
book = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
data = get_cell_range_values(sheet, "A3", "A130")
```

Keep in mind that you only get linear ranges, don't create matrix